# Chrome and fixed width on a div (or other tags)

Tags: google-chrome, width, fixed, fixed-width

I have some html which looks like this:

```
<div style="{ display:inline; width: 80px}">fig</div>vitamin c<br>
<div style="{ display:inline; width: 80px}">apple</div>vitamin a<br>
<div style="{ display:inline; width: 80px}">coconut</div>vitamin <br>
```

in IE.8 this is shown as

```
fig       vitamin
apple     vitamin
coconut   vitamin
```

and all of the 'vitamins' are nicely aligned. 
in Chrome the gap is not created and therefore it is not nicely rendered.

```
figvitamin
applevitamin
coconutvitamin
```

The question is:
is this a problem/bug with Chrome or is it because the html is not correct and ie8 (in this case) just guesses better my intentions ?

Comment: Try <span style="margin-left:25px;">vitamin c</span>

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: that would still not align the different 'vitamins' below one another, tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox are correct. Width is not a valid style property for inline elements. You have several options:

### Inline Blocks

You can do this:

```
<span>fig</span>vitamin<br>
<span>apple</span>vitamin<br>
<span>coconut</span>vitamin
```

with:

```
span { display: inline-block; width: 80px; }
```

You'll notice I used `<span>` instead of `<div>`. There is a reason for this. `<span>`s are naturally `display: inline` and according to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock):

> In IE 6 and 7 `inline-block` works
>   only on elements that have a natural
>   `display: inline`.
>
> Firefox 2 and lower don't support this
>   value. You can use `-moz-inline-box`,
>   but be aware that it's not the same as
>   `inline-block`, and it may not work as
>   you expect in some situations.

### Floats

You can float the left labels:

```
<div>fig</div>vitamin<br>
<div>apple</div>vitamin<br>
<div>coconut</div>vitamin
```

with:

```
div { float: left; clear: left; width: 80px; }
```

If the text after the `<div>` is sufficiently large it will wrap to the *beginning* of the line (not with the 80px buffer). You might want that or not.

### Definition List

Using this markup:

```
<dl>
  <dt>fig</dt><dd>vitamin</dd>
  <dt>apple</dt><dd>vitamin</dd>
  <dt>coconut</dt><dd>vitamin</dd>
</dl>
```

with:

```
dt { float: left; width: 80px; }
```

### Tables

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="left">fig</td>
  <td>vitamin</td>
</tr>
  <td>apple</td>
  <td>vitamin</td>
</tr>
  <td>coconut</td>
  <td>vitamin</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

with:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td.left { width: 80px; }
```

Tables will be by far the most backward compatible solution (going back to IE5 or earlier) so they're still often used in situations where some might argue they aren't appropriate. The ideals of the so-called *semantic Web* are well-intentioned and worth adhering to where possible but you'll also often end up in situations where you're choosing between "semantic purity" and backwards compatibility so a certain amount of pragmatism needs to prevail.

That being said, unless you're not telling us something, you shouldn't need to go this path if you don't want to.

Lastly, **always** put a DOCTYPE declaration on your pages. It forces IE from quirks mode to standards compliant mode (both euphemisms). For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
...
```

Comment: Thanks Cletus. 
Can you tell me a bit more ? Since Width is not a valid style property for inline elements which one would you think it's the most efficient fix.
I would be inclined to work out the spaces for every fruit name so that they all have the same length (let's say 20 chars long)
and then put a fixed font. 
but is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Once again thanks Cletus. 
However I tried your 'inline blocks' solution and 'floats' solution.
And I can tell you they both don't work in Chrome. 
So in the 'inline blocks' why does chrome ignore my fixed width ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a div that is floated to the left for the headings - this is popular for two column forms and the like on websites that don't want to use tables, or need more flexibility that the strict layout that a table restricts you to.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="float: left; width: 80px;">Banana</div>
    <div>Vitamin Awesome</div>
</div>
```

I guess the outer div could be replaced with a `<br clear="both" />` afterwards.